# how to know if this is the first time your user has downloaded your desktop application

Tags: electron, desktop-application, desktop

I wanted to do like in games.  When it's your first download, the game shows you a tutorial.  Even some apps do that.  Is there any way to know if this is the first time that user is downloading my desktop application?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43711738/how-to-detect-that-the-electron-app-is-running-for-the-first-time